# AS3/AIR desktop application: I can not type vietnamese on s:Textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>  
        <![CDATA[
            private function resetPrompts():void { 
                myTextInput.text = ""; 
                myTextArea.text = ""; 
            } 
        ]]>  
    </fx:Script>  
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="myTextInput" prompt="Enter name..." fontFamily="Marker Felt Thin" /> 
        <s:TextArea id="myTextArea" prompt="Triệu hổ..." fontFamily="A"/> 
        <s:Button label="Reset" click="resetPrompts()"/> 
    </s:VGroup>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

As my code: I use this tool to write Vietnamese character: http://unikey.vn/vietnam/
but any special char: ê, ô, í, ì... has been removed..

Comment: Is your font supporting these characters ? Many fonts only have the standard latin characters (and maybe some european specifics). Does it work if you remove fontFamily="A" and use the device fonts?

Comment: I removed fontFamily but it still can't type vietnamese.

Comment: Does the textfield now using device fonts ? Like Arial font on windows? You might have a font family specified for the TextArea globally in the css for example. Do you see the special characters if you set an initial text for the textarea? For example text="Triệu hổ..."?

Comment: global {fontFamily: "Arial";}  
s|TextArea {fontFamily: "Arial";} 
I add above code. It still can't. :D

Comment: If I use mx:Textarea, I can type vietnamese. But s:texarea is can not.